# ubuntu-desktop in lxc with ubuntu server as the host

Tags: xorg, lxd

I've recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 server and would like to use it as a desktop without interfering too much with the server part.

This should be possible using linux containers (lxd). The problem is that when I launch an ubuntu container, install ubuntu-desktop in it, mount /dev/tty7, and run xinit, two things happen:

1) black screen with a motionless cursor (not mouse) in the top left. keyboard doesn't work, requires restart
2) in the Xorg log, I find this error:

> xf86EnableIOPorts: failed to set IOPL for I/O (Operation not permitted)

Answer (score 1):

It should be doable to launch an X11 server in a LXD container when there is no X11 server running on the host.

See [this post](https://blog.simos.info/how-to-run-graphics-accelerated-gui-apps-in-lxd-containers-on-your-ubuntu-desktop/) for details on running X11 apps in a container and directing the output to an existing X11 server on the host. In this post there is a `prerequisite` section which you have to attend to here as well.

For this distinct case of running the full X11 server inside a LXD container, you would need to pass any necessary devices from the host into the container, making sure that the ownership and permission mode is suitable for each. You may need to upgrade to LXD 3.2 (snap package) if there is an issue with specifying the ownership or mode of a device.

To go back to your original question, it would help to list the devices that you are trying to push into the container, and their ownership/mode.

Answer (score 1):

The above link to Simos's blog shows one approach to running a gui in LXD container.

Alexandre Dey's published a GitHub which has a very good method as well and is actually a bit more flexible in terms of supporting multiple users of the LXD container desktop.

https://github.com/AlexandreDey/ContainerBox

Alexandre is currently working on updating ContainerBox documentation as well as I believe implementing the newe LXD 3.x.x Device PROXY capability for the graphics & audio.  (read the "issues" section comment about this on his github page).  You should read all of those "issues" anyway because until he updates the documentation some of what are in the comments clarifies what is currently missing in his current README file.